# Nifi error with fetchelasticsearch processor

Tags: elasticsearch, dataflow, apache-nifi

I'm getting strange error while running the FetchElasticSearch processor, below is the error.

FetchElasticsearch[id=f2b2fee3-b940-4a73-8a28-0436e765c9a2] Failed to read into Elasticsearch due to None of the configured nodes are available: [{#transport#-1}{127.0.0.1}{localhost/127.0.0.1:9500}], this may indicate an error in configuration (hosts, username/password, etc.). Routing to retry: NoNodeAvailableException[None of the configured nodes are available: [{#transport#-1}{127.0.0.1}{localhost/127.0.0.1:9500}]] 2016-08-30 11:58:17,930 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-3] o.a.n.p.elasticsearch.FetchElasticsearch org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: None of the configured nodes are available: [{#transport#-1}{127.0.0.1}{localhost/127.0.0.1:9500}] at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.ensureNodesAreAvailable(TransportClientNodesService.java:290) ~[elasticsearch-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0] at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.execute(TransportClientNodesService.java:207) ~[elasticsearch-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0] at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.support.TransportProxyClient.execute(TransportProxyClient.java:55) ~[elasticsearch-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0] at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.doExecute(TransportClient.java:283) ~[elasticsearch-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0] at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient.execute(AbstractClient.java:347) ~[elasticsearch-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0] at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.execute(ActionRequestBuilder.java:85) ~[elasticsearch-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0] at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.execute(ActionRequestBuilder.java:59) ~[elasticsearch-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0] at org.apache.nifi.processors.elasticsearch.FetchElasticsearch.onTrigger(FetchElasticsearch.java:164) ~[nifi-elasticsearch-processors-0.7.0.jar:0.7.0] at org.apache.nifi.processor.AbstractProcessor.onTrigger(AbstractProcessor.java:27) [nifi-api-0.7.0.jar:0.7.0] at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.onTrigger(StandardProcessorNode.java:1054) [nifi-framework-core-0.7.0.jar:0.7.0] at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.call(ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.java:136) [nifi-framework-core-0.7.0.jar:0.7.0] at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.call(ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.java:47) [nifi-framework-core-0.7.0.jar:0.7.0] at org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent$1.run(TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent.java:127) [nifi-framework-core-0.7.0.jar:0.7.0] at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_91] at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308) [na:1.8.0_91] at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [na:1.8.0_91] at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294) [na:1.8.0_91] at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_91] at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_91] at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_91]

ElasticSearch configurations are :

Host : localhost

port : 9500

not sure about the root cause of the problem, do the needful.

Answer (score 0):

FetchElasticsearch uses the native Transport API, whose default port is 9300. Did you change it to 9500 on your Elasticsearch cluster? If not then 9300 should work, see this article for more details:
https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/53973/nifi-error-with-fetchelasticsearch-processornifi-e.html